# Replace electric water heater with gas tankless (electrical connection)

Tags: receptacle, hot-water, 120-240v

I want to replace my electric water heater with a gas tankless water heater. My current water heater like most electric hot water heaters takes 220 and the tankless gas water heater uses 120. The room I am installing in has no outlets. Can I use that 220 line and get a couple out 120 15 or 20a outlets out of it. Maybe with a sub panel type set up or if I can't do that if I can at least wire the new 120 water heater without running a new line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many wires are in the cable to this water heater and what color are they?

Comment: It is 10/2 ROMEX. The color I am not 100% sure as I have not in hooked it from the water heater yet. I assume it black white and bare.

Comment: 10/2 + gnd? So you will get one 120-V  20-A circuit out of it which will certainly do for the tankless gas water heater which will draw practically nothing since the power is just for the controls. I presume this room has no gas supply currently so you will have to bring in a 3/4" or 1" gas line for the new gas water heater and you will have to have a flue installed.  All this on top of the purchase price of the water heater will be $$$$. Is the current electric tank WH inadequate? What size room is this? Is a furnace also in this room?

Comment: Do you know if your house has a large enough gas line to supply a tankless gas water heater? Where will you get combustion air? A new house under construction in our neighborhood is being fitted with two 180,000 BTU/h tankless heaters which each exhaust through the roof through a coaxial intake air/vent to also bring in combustion air. The house has a 1.5" main gas line (meter to house to attic) which then divides into smaller diameter for various gas appliances.

Comment: Thirteen years ago I changed our 40-gal gas tank water heater to a minimal discontinued model Bosch 125 B rated at 120,000 BTU/h. I just used the gas line for the old tank which had a 40,000 BTU/h burner. We may not be getting full heating capacity, but it works for two 75-year-old retirees who don't demand a lot. This Bosch tankless doesn't have electronic diagnostics, and works on a standing pilot light! The plumber at the new house told me that the new Rinnai tankless heaters he is installing will give an error code if they are starved of gas.

Comment: Our Furnace just went up so we are considering installing a gas one. While we are at it I feel we will see a greater savings by switching our water heater too. They are next to each other. I plan to run a 1" main line in to a manifold and run 3/4 off for the water heater and the furnace total run well under 50'. I figure between the savings in using gas instead of all electric and the added benefit of unlimited hot water it is well worth it. I plan on doing as much of the work my self as I can and water heater should be pretty easy because my whole house is PEX.

Comment: I plan on running Concentric vent horizontal and exit out the side of my house. There are no windows on that side so no worries there.

Comment: Do you mean that you are going to run separate 3/4" lines one to the water heater and one to the gas furnace? I don't think that a single 3/4" line 50' long would feed both. Probably you should have a 1" line going into the water heater/furnace closet and only the final run of a few feet  to 10 ft 3/4" to the water heater and the same to the furnace. Later someone might want a 199,000 BTU/h tankless water heater or maybe  even two tankless water heaters totalling over 300,000 BTU/h.

Comment: I mean i will run a 1" line about 26' to a manifold then from the manifold i will run a 3/4 line 5' from the manifold to the furnace then another 3/4 line 2' from the manifold to the water heater. then a 3/4 line 22' from the manifold to the range for future use. and a 3/4 line 15' from the manifold to the dryer again for future use. I would consider going bigger than 1" for the main line but my gas company only supports a 1" line from the road to the meter and 1" out of the meter so going bigger probably does not make much since.

Comment: It may actually make more since to run 1" 20' or so tee off for the furnace since the pipe will go right by it and then continue with 1" another 6' or so then build my manifold and go off it with 3/4" one line for water heater, one line for dryer and one line for range and maybe leave and empty one for future expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the panel, move the white wire to the neutral bar, and move the black to a 20A breaker.   Fit a 15A or 20A duplex receptacle.  And you're done.

You can use up to about 19.5 amps of power off that receptacle, since the water heater won't take much.

If you want two full circuits good for a total of 30A@120V, in the main panel, leave the black wire on the 30A breaker, still move white to neutral. Then fit a subpanel, of any size.  Black to a hot pole, white to the neutral bar, ground to a different ground bar that is isolated from neutral.  Only every other row of breaker spaces will work. Fit two 15A or 20A breakers and use each one for a different circuit.   If you place the breakers in the wrong row, don't bust out more knockouts, switch the black wire to the other hot lug.

Comment: Are both of these options within code? I like the second option better but don't want to create a mess if I go to sell the house.

Comment: Absolutely it is. They don't really make 120V panels,  don't need to.   Your other option is split the black wire with a wirenut and two pigtails (same size wire) and feed both hot lugs, but that is uglier because it has the illusion of 240V power but is not.

Comment: If there is not a 4 wire feed to the waterheater this will not be legal, straight 240v water heaters do not require a 4 wire but a sub panel would, running a 120v panel would be a waste in my opinion with 10 awg wire.

Comment: @EdBeal explain why does a 120V subpanel need a 240V feed? We are retasking the white wire to be actual neutral.  There is no second hot.

Comment: I think it would be a waste to install a single pole sub the panel , breaker & outlets required are close to 10× just replacing with a duplex 120 in my experiance most water heaters are close to the main if a sub is needed and it is not it is a waste of $ in my opinion to install a hack like this. Just my opinion but the jobs I have replaced like this were usually DIY with no thought and the new owners thought they had a real sub not a hack job,,, I have seen this 2 or 3 times over my years and they were all upgraded properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would swap out the 240v double pole breaker for a 120v single pole and change the outlet. It is ok to use larger wire as most water heaters are wired with3 wire 10 awg this is small for a sub and the sub would need 4 wire. If wired 4 wire #8 I would put in a small sub, but if 10awg just convert it to 120v you need.